# How to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Entity Framework Entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have an EF 5 entity called Account generated with the standard template.

It has a property AccountTypeId.

When it changes, I need a notification so another field can be updated.

How is this typically done?  This is needed for only one property, so I don't want to use a modified template.

AccountTypeId is bound to a ComboBox in the UI in WinForms, so it's not really an MVVM app as I would normally do in WPF.

Comment: Which version of EF?  How is the entity generated?

Comment: Using EF 5 and the standard templates.

Comment: You could modify the T4 template to emit a property that supported `IPropertyChanged`, or you could create a custom template for that one entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to go to the EDMX and rename the field to AccountTypeID_Internal (for example), and in the EDMX set the property to `Private`.  Then create a Partial Class.

Generated Account.cs should look like:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace <yournamespace>
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Account
    {
        private int AccountTypeId_Internal  { get; set; }

        // other auto generated properties
    }
}
```

Account.Partial.Cs

```
public partial class Account : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Int AccountTypeId
  {
    get
    {
      return this.AccountTypeId_Internal;
    }
    set
    {
      this.AccountTypeId_Internal = value;
      // Do INotifyPropertyChangedLogic
    }
  }

  // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

The advantage of this is that your already written code doesn't have to change at all.  The downside is that if you remove the Accout from the edmx and re-add it you will have to go through the edmx steps again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a few lines of code using a NuGet package called [PropertyChanged.Fody](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PropertyChanged.Fody/). The package documentation is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged). See my CodeProject tip ["Adding INotifyPropertyChanged to Entity Framework Classes](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/853383/Adding-INotifyPropertyChanged-to-Entity-Framework)".

I should point out that that technique will implement INPC for every property in the class.  If you only want INPC for a single property and you don't want to modify the T4 template or EDMX file then you could leverage the fact that the entity classes are generated with the "partial" keyword, allowing you to add a "wrapper" property in a separate (non-generated) file like Erik Philips described.  You would have to modify your existing code to reference the wrapper property but nothing would break when you re-generate the model or entities.